# Register Revenge of the Titans on Steam

Tags: steam, revenge-of-the-titans

Can I register on Steam my copy of `Revenge of the Titans`, obtained buying the Humble Indie Bundle 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, find the email originally sent by the Humble Bundle with the link to your download page. At the top of the page, there is a header that reads, "Click here for your Steam, Desura, and OnLive keys."

Comment: Please note that this will currently only work for the Windows version of RotT. The Mac version is not yet available on Steam.